# Debian 11 Sound problem after upgrade

Tags: pulseaudio

I am using Debian 11. sudo apt-get upgrade Then I started having sound problems. Sometimes when I stop watching a video and turn it on after a few minutes, there is no sound from the computer.

[Settings -> Sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bFTZ.png)

[pulse volume control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ7iY.png)

[command: /sbin/lsmod | grep snd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McVsw.png)

It fixes itself when I run the commands below and change the Announcer from Settings -> Sound.

```
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/remove
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

But it happens again after a while.

Comment: Welcome to Unix! It is best to put command output in the listing as text. This allows for searching and web search hits.